# Perfecto Mobile - same image on different devices

Tags: testing, mobile

What should I do to get the best image matching on multiple devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use the bounded size. Any size is too slow and same size is only good for devices that are the same. The parameters for bounded size are hard to understand but in general, for
needle bound - Use 30% for a script that runs on devices only, and 70% for a script that includes tablets.
For the haystack area - I don't understand this. I just keep the default.